# How to grab text from textview when working with spinners

Tags: android, null, textview, spinner, nullreferenceexception

so I'm trying to make a drop down menu where the each item on the menu corresponds to the name of a city (New York, Los Angeles, San Francisco, etc). The number of cities/items on the drop down menu is different for each user, so I can't use a switch statement. So let me walk you guys through the code so it makes sense.

1)I first make this CitySpinner ArrayAdapter and in that class, I have a method called getCustomView which returns me a view.

```
  public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_cityfolder,parent,false);

        TextView cityName = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvLanguage);

        ImageView cityImage = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imgLanguage);

        cityName.setText(foldersArrayList.get(position).getName());
        cityImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.small_icon_bar);

        return layout;
    }

    // It gets a View that displays in the drop down popup the data at the specified position
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
```

2)Now in the activity where I display the dropdown menu I make an instance a spinner, called dropDownSpinner and pass in the citySpinner adapter.

```
 citySpinner = new CitySpinner(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.spinner_cityfolder,Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().cityFoldersArrayList);

dropDownspinner.setAdapter(citySpinner);
```

3)Then i do onItemSelectedListener, and in here I'm trying to get the text of the name of the folder they click on. Then compare it to all the names of cities which I have in some global arraylist. And if they match, get me certain information. But the problem is, when I use folderName.getText() below, it's referencing null. Is there anyway I can get the text of the current view?

```
   dropDownspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)//Create a class that returns a custom View that's a textView of the city Name.
                            {
                                check++;
                                if(check > 1)
                                {
                                    TextView folderName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLanguage);
                                    for(CityFolders TempFolders: Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().cityFoldersArrayList)
                                    {
                                        if(adapterView.getAdapter().equals(citySpinner))
                                        {
                                            if(((CitySpinner) adapterView.getAdapter()).getCityName(i).equals(TempFolders.getName()))
                                            {
                                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),((CitySpinner) adapterView.getAdapter()).getCityName(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                Spinner newDropDownSpiner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                                                newDropDownSpiner.setAdapter(new CardSpinner(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.spinner_cards,TempFolders.getCards()));
                                                //dropDownspinner.setAdapter(new CardSpinner(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_cards, TempFolders.getCards()));
                                                break;


                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                //Do nothing
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not the same type of spinner",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }

                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //Do nothing
                                }
                            }
```

Here is my stacktrace:

12-22 13:58:29.627 9553-9553/com.lorentzos.swipecards.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
    Process: com.lorentzos.swipecards.example, PID: 9553


java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.lorentzos.swipecards.MyActivity$1$1.onItemSelected(MyActivity.java:176)
                                                                                at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:914)
                                                                                at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:903)
                                                                                at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:48)
                                                                                at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:873)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5430)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Layout for tvLanguage

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:background="#434343">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLanguage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLanguage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Text Here"
        android:textColor="#86f6e7">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the xml of the layout that `tvLanguage` is in?

Comment: @Andrew Brooke yeah i posted it above.

Answer (score 1):

`CitySpinner` is your adapter so you can do in this way:

```
dropDownspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <? > adapterView, View view, int i, long l) //Create a class tha returns a custom View that's a textView of the city Name.
{
    check++;
    if (check > 1) {
        TextView folderName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLanguage);
        for (CityFolders TempFolders: Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().cityFoldersArrayList) {
            if ( (adapterView.getAdapter() instanceof CitySpinner) && ((CitySpinner)adapterView.getAdapter()).getCityAt(i).equals(TempFolders.getName()))
            {
                dropDownspinner.setAdapter(new CardSpinner(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_cards, TempFolders.getCards()));
                break;


            } else {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }

    } else {
        //Do nothing
    }
}
```

And provide the `getCityAt` in your adapter:

```
//...
public String getCityAt(int position){
   return foldersArrayList.get(position).getName();
}
//...
```

Comment: dude thanks so much it almost works. So i did a toast of the city folder name it works. But when i put back the dropDownSpinner.setAdapter(...) line i keep getting this error:



ava.lang.ClassCastException: com.lorentzos.swipecards.Spinners.CardSpinner cannot be cast to com.lorentzos.swipecards.Spinners.CitySpinner

Comment: the error line is on the if statement. I mean there is nothing wrong with the if statement i think, but when i reset the adapter it says that I cannot cast CardSpinner to a citySpinner when I'm not doing that, or at least thinking of doing that.

Comment: I just update the if statement, now checking if the adapter is effectively a CitySpinner. Check it out and check if it works now.

Comment: so yeah i updated the code above and i did an if statement to check if its the same spinner and its not apparently. But im at lost to why that is.

Comment: so, it toasts, "Not the same type of spinner" in the else statement

Comment: so its just a problem with my CardSpinner class, I think its a bug i can solve from here. But thanks so much for your support guys! you solved my initial problem of getting the name of the folder!